# How to reset value of input file upload on unchecking mat-checkbox in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I created a File upload button using this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-button-qgpeu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffile-upload-button%2Ffile-upload-button.component.ts).

Using this i have made a structure like this

**Image 1**

[image]

On Checkbox check, I have made condition that if checkbox is checked than file upload button will enable otherwise by default file upload button will disable.

**Image 2**

[image]

As show as `Image 2` if I checked checkbox than file upload button will enable and now i can upload image as show as below `Image 3`.

**Image 3**

[image]

Now if i uncheck `mat-checkbox` than i want to reset value of file upload input. Because as show as `Image 4` file upload button is disable but it has value its look not proper as development side.

**Image 4**

[image]

**HTML file code**

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="printCoverPage" class="generate-check" (change)="triggerDisableImage()" >Cover Page</mat-checkbox>

<div class="generate-button">
    <button class="btn-style red-btn file-upload-button" type="button" [disabled]="isDisabled">
      <span class="material-icons">image</span>Upload Cover Image
      <input type="file" #fileCoverImage (change)="onCoverImage(fileCoverImage)" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" [disabled]="isDisabled" />
    </button>
    <span class="file-info">{{ this.fileCoverInfo }}</span>
</div>
```

**TS file**

```
export class GenerateIAPComponent implements OnInit {

isDisabled = true;
triggerDisableImage() {
    this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    return;
}

onCoverImage(input: HTMLInputElement): void {
    function formatBytes(bytes: number): string {
      const UNITS = ['Bytes', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
      const factor = 1024;
      let index = 0;
      while (bytes >= factor) {
        bytes /= factor;
        index++;
      }
      return `${parseFloat(bytes.toFixed(2))} ${UNITS[index]}`;
    }
    // @ts-ignore
    const file = input.files[0];
    this.fileCoverImage = file;
    this.fileCoverInfo = `${file.name} (${formatBytes(file.size)})`;
}
```

So is there any solution to reset value of file upload on uncheck `mat-checkbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reset the values of `this.fileCoverImage` and `this.fileCoverInfo` in `triggerDisableImage()` when the checkbox is disabled as follows:

```
triggerDisableImage() {
    this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    if (this.isDisabled) {
       this.fileCoverImage = null;
       this.fileCoverInfo = null;
    }
    return;
}
```